kivy-ios ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'kivymd'
I have been trying to compile my kivy/kivymd project for ios, however after following the kivy-ios documentation and trying different way of building the xcode project I keep getting stuck at a ModuleNotFoundError indicating I don't have kivymd installed. Upon executing sudo toolchain pip install kivymd==1.1.1 it works, I check through toolchain pip list where kivymd is present. I tried clean building, creating a new project, building with Pillow (All status of built recipes are OK), yet no luck. I usually never post but I am truly stuck and I can't find anything online which helps me in this case.
PS: I am using python==3.9.6, cython==0.29.36 (also tried 3.0.0) and running on MacOS Sonoma 14.4.1. (There are no errors with the python code before you ask, it's already built for android and working fine and did no changes which could cause errors)
I would be eternally thankful to anyone who can help me in this regard. Thank you in advance.

Also have the same error, is it not possible to use kivymd on IOS?

I managed to get past the error by adding kivymd directly into my project folder (alongside main.py). If you right click on your project folder (YourApp - left hand panel) and click "Add file to project" or something, then go find kivymd and add it in here. No idea if it works and probably not best practice but it moved me on to a new error!
